# flash actionscript 2.0 and php

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

i hop to help me for this please.
the problem is i want to get a text came from database random and not to be Duplicates
and this text be in a move clip this move clip will be in the stage random 10 Times .
the game is about solder in Minefield and when he come to the mine it Asks question the answer will be (yes or no).
i create the character and make its moves.
i create the move that is a mine and come random in the stage.
i create a text in this move clip (that i want to get text from the database by random and not to be duplicates to be in anther mine )

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate issues and need to be handled separately.

1. You can return random from a database directly using SQL.
2. As for avoiding duplicates you need to maintain an internal list to avoid creating a duplicate.  Otherwise you will have to manage the random bit and the duplicates within flash itself, grab all the possible texts from the database and handle there rest internally.  Randomly select one from the list, mark it blacklisted.  There are a number of approaches, off the top of my head you could maintain two lists.  One for unselected "texts" and one for selected "texts".  You can then randomly select from the unselected list and move it to the selected list, to avoid selecting it twice.

Comment: i know this i make a two tables for this one have a data and the anther i will insert into it the data that i will take but i don't know the action script cod that i will used for this 
i have tray a code but it make the game Heavy and the character has been walk slowly
i want a code that make this